# BraTS data normalization

Tags: python, image-processing, data-preprocessing

I'm currently working on a Super resolution algorithm using the BraTS18 dataset.
I have a problem When it comes to data normalization between [-1, 1].

```
from tqdm import tqdm
import os
import numpy as np
import SimpleITK as sitk

def load_data(path, length=32, offset=0):
  if length == None:
    my_dir = sorted(os.listdir(path))
  else:
    my_dir = sorted(os.listdir(path)[offset:offset+length])
  data = []
  gt = []
  for p in tqdm(my_dir):
    data_list = sorted(os.listdir(path+p))
    img_itk = sitk.ReadImage(path + p + '/'+ data_list[0])
    flair = sitk.GetArrayFromImage(img_itk)
    data.append(flair)
  data = np.asarray(data,dtype=np.float32)
  data = data[:, 30:120, 30:222, 30:222].reshape([-1, 192, 192])
  return data
```

at first I thought that the values were in the range [0, 255], but as I tried

```
data_test = load_data_test(pathHGG, length=None)
np.max(data_test)
```

I got the value (32767.0), and now I'm confused about the range of the values of the data on BraTS flair.
Can anyone tell me how I'm supposed to perform a pixel normalization?

Answer (score 0):

After further research I found that each volume of data (every flair file) should be normalized according to its values due to the bias on the contrast from MRI to MRI. I hope this helps someone that stumbles on my question.
Here is my new code:

```
def load_data(path, length=32, offset=0):
  if length == None:
    my_dir = sorted(os.listdir(path))
  else:
    my_dir = sorted(os.listdir(path)[offset:offset+length])
  data = []
  for p in tqdm(my_dir):
    data_list = sorted(os.listdir(path+p))
    img_itk = sitk.ReadImage(path + p + '/'+ data_list[0])
    #flair
    data.append(sitk.GetArrayFromImage(img_itk))
  #convert to numpy array
  data = np.asarray(data, dtype=np.float32)
  #Remove what is useless
  data = data[:, 30:120, 30:222, 30:222]
  #normalize each volume using minmax method
  for i in range(data.shape[0]):
    data[i, ...] = (data[i, ...] - np.min(data[i, ...]))*2/(np.max(data[i, ...]) - np.min(data[i, ...])) - 1

  data = data.reshape([-1, data.shape[2], data.shape[3]])
  return data
```